# Deploy modified neo4j-browser with neo4j as a new neo4j docker image?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I modified neo4j-browser.

**How can I deploy new neo4j docker image that uses modified neo4j-browser?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it with Dockerfile.
You will need your customized neo4j-browser jar file. In order to generate jar file run `yarn prepare-jar` and `yarn jar` commands in this repo  [neo4j-browser](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser).

```
FROM neo4j:latest

RUN rm /var/lib/neo4j/data \
    && mkdir /var/lib/neo4j/data \
    && mv /data/* /var/lib/neo4j/data/

COPY ./neo4j-browser-3.1.4.jar /var/lib/neo4j/lib/neo4j-browser-3.1.4.jar

EXPOSE 7474 7473 7687

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["neo4j"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to pack your build with a modified browser (and other changes), make it available by http, and change the distribution's address in the [docker's Makefile](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/blob/master/Makefile#L18) of the local copy `docker-neo4j`:

```
dist_site := http://my_personal_neo_build
```

and then rebuild your own image.